# Unable to implement menu click on FRAGMENT calls main activity every time

Tags: android, menu, android-fragments, fragment, android-menu

When i click on the Menu of my FRAGMENT its redirect to main activity.
It is not implementing "onOptionsItemSelected" of FRAGMENT.Cant override onOptionsItemSelected of  main activity.
Please suggest what is the problem below is the code.

```
public class Word_quiz_game extends Fragment implements ActionMode.Callback ,OnClickListener
{
TextView c0, c1, c2, c3, q, qNa;
TextView lang_txt;
static String langType;
ActionBar actionBar;
ProgressDialog loadingDialog;
Context context;
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context=getActivity().getBaseContext();
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_quiz_game, container, false);


    try {

        context=getActivity().getBaseContext();         

        final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
           StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
           .detectCustomSlowCalls() 
           .detectDiskReads()
           .detectDiskWrites()
           .detectNetwork()
           .penaltyLog()
           .penaltyFlashScreen() 
           .build());



           StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
           .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
           .detectLeakedClosableObjects() 
           .setClassInstanceLimit(Class.forName("com.shabdkosh.left_tab.Word_quiz_game"), 100)
           .penaltyLog()
           .build());


        System.out.println(" " + sharedPreferences.getString("lang", "en"));
        map = getWordQuiz(sharedPreferences.getString("lang", "en"));


        qNa = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.prvs_ans);
        q = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.q_txt);
        c0 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.first_txt);
        c1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.second_txt);
        c2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.third_txt);
        c3 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fourth_txt);


        Typeface hin_font  = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), hindi_font);
        qNa.setTypeface(hin_font);
        q.setTypeface(hin_font);
        c0.setTypeface(hin_font);
        c1.setTypeface(hin_font);
        c2.setTypeface(hin_font);
        c3.setTypeface(hin_font);

        c0.setOnClickListener(this);
        c1.setOnClickListener(this);
        c2.setOnClickListener(this);
        c3.setOnClickListener(this);


        LinearLayout adscontainer = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adsContainer);
        View admobAds = (View) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView1);        
        if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).contains("PAYMENT_DONE")){
            if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean("PAYMENT_DONE", false)){
                adscontainer.removeView(admobAds);  
            }

        }

        if (q.getText().toString() == "" | c0.getText().toString() == ""
                | c1.getText().toString() == ""
                | c2.getText().toString() == ""
                | c3.getText().toString() == "") {

            map = getWordQuiz(sharedPreferences.getString("lang", "en"));
            q.setText(map.get("question"));
            c0.setText(map.get("c0"));
            c1.setText(map.get("c1"));
            c2.setText(map.get("c2"));
            c3.setText(map.get("c3"));
        }

        qNa.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("lastAnswer", " "));



    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return rootView;
}
```

And below is the onOptionsItemSelected method

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{

    item.collapseActionView();
    SharedPreferences shrdPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    shrdPref.edit().remove("lastAnswer").commit();      
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.Hindi:

    if (R.id.Hindi == item.getItemId()) 

    {
        String languageToLoad = "hi"; // language
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString("lang", "hi").commit();
        getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new Word_quiz_game()).commit();


    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.hin_sel), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
    }

    return true;
    case R.id.English:

    if (R.id.English == item.getItemId()) 
    {
        String languageToLoad = "en"; // language
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;

        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString("lang", "en").commit();
        getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_container, new Word_quiz_game())
        .commit();

    }
    else 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.Al_Eng_sel), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: lets start by, why cant you override the acitivities onOptionsItemSelected? is there some code doing stuff which leads to the activity not passing the event to the fragment? have you tried adding a sysout in the onOptionsSelected of the fragment, no matter the id?

Comment: Ya every time i press on action bar menu,it is calling the main activity onOptionItemSelected method and that activity is displayed,not the fragment content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented on main activity of onPrepareOptionMenu and used if condition for every fragment..
But its an alteration still dint get ans for my question calling onPrepareOptionMenu of Fragment.
Anyways thanks everyone for your reply